# how i can get id from table on codeigniter?

Tags: mysql

I have a query and I try it on phpmyadmin and it works.

```
SELECT  * FROM `penyakit` LEFT JOIN puskesmas ON penyakit.id_puskesmas=puskesmas.id_puskesmas WHERE (YEAR(waktu_upload) = 2018 AND MONTH(waktu_upload) = 12)  AND penyakit.id_puskesmas = 19
```

I using this query for my filter function like this:

```
function status_data($year,$month){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('puskesmas');
    $this->db->group_by('puskesmas.nama_puskesmas');
    $this->db->join('penyakit', 'puskesmas.id_puskesmas=penyakit.id_puskesmas', 'left');

    $data= $this->db->get()->result();

    foreach ($data as $value) {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `penyakit` LEFT JOIN puskesmas ON penyakit.id_puskesmas=puskesmas.id_puskesmas WHERE YEAR(waktu_upload) = '$year' AND MONTH(waktu_upload) = '$month' 
            AND puseksmas.id_puskesmas=".$value->id_puskesmas);

        $num = $query->num_rows();

         $value->num = $num;
        if($num < 19 ){
            $value->status = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-rounded'> Uncomplete</button>";
        }else{
            $value->status = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-rounded'> Complete </button>";
        }

    }
    //die(print_r($data));
    return $data;
}
```

But this query cant get id and show error like this.

> SELECT * FROM `penyakit` LEFT JOIN puskesmas ON penyakit.id_puskesmas=puskesmas.id_puskesmas WHERE YEAR(waktu_upload) = '2018' AND MONTH(waktu_upload) = '12' AND puseksmas.id_puskesmas=

This id not showed. How I can fix this?

Comment: plese update your question with the output of `var_dump($value);die();`  placed as the first line inside `foreach` loop

Comment: ok and this error like this

Comment: object(stdClass)#22 (11) {
  ["id_puskesmas"]=>
  NULL
  ["nama_puskesmas"]=>
  string(18) "Puskesmas Gemolong"
  ["alamat_puskesmas"]=>
  string(45) "Jl. Gatot Subroto, Nglangak, Kwangen, Gemolon"
  ["nama_petugas"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["nomor"]=>
  string(10) "081xxxxxxx"
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["format"]=>
  NULL
  ["nama_file"]=>
  NULL
  ["waktu_upload"]=>
  NULL
  ["jenis"]=>
  NULL
}

Comment: this id_puskesmas is null

Comment: so what's the question then? If it's null you need to either figure out what the previous query with left outer join returns and if it's expected, then add a check for non-empty `id_puskesmas`